# How can I spawn a Python multiprocess with the same arguments as the parent process?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to parallelize the `do_something()` method of a python script using multiprocessing. The actual processing within `do_something()` varies depending on a value in the parent process (passed in via cli parameter).

Is there a way I can pass this value to the spawned processes? The new processes don't need to change/persist the value, but rather just read it.

Here is an example of code that fails with a `NameError: name 'args' is not defined`

```
import argparse
import collections
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_context


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--foo', required=True, type=int)
    global args # need this if I'm reading from threads / forks
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print('This prints fine')
    with get_context('spawn').Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = collections.deque(pool.imap_unordered(do_something, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 0)

    print(results)
    return

def do_something(i):
    if args.foo > 0:
        print('do something')
    else:
        print('do something else')
    return i

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**How can I pass `args.foo` to the spawned processes?**

Edit: I've learned about initializers, but the problem persists. This gives me the same NameError as above:

```
import argparse
import collections
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_context


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--foo', required=True, type=int)
    global args # need this if I'm reading from threads / forks
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print('This prints fine')
    with get_context('spawn').Pool(processes=4, initializer=init(args)) as pool:
        results = collections.deque(pool.imap_unordered(do_something, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]), 0)

    print(results)
    return

def init(n):
    global args
    args = n

def do_something(i):
    if args.foo > 0:
        print('do something')
    else:
        print('do something else')
    return i

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You need to pass in args to the function. making args a global variable does not work because the new process never executes code in the main.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction to doing that with imap? I'm not sure how additional arguments work in the map/imap model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `initializer` code is on the right track, but you're not doing it quite right. When you pass the keyword argument `initializer=init(args)` in the `Pool` contructor, you're calling `init` in the main process and passing its return value (`None`) as the initializer for the pool. That's not what you want.

Instead, you need to just pass `init` as the `initializer` argument, and pass the arguments it takes separately as `initargs`. That lets the pool call the function in each child process. It should look like this:

```
with get_context('spawn').Pool(processes=4, initializer=init, initargs=(args,)) as pool:
    ...
```

Comment: Ah. I wasn't expecting that. Thank you for your help!